# Query with join not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i am doing a query in my controller like this:

```
$aviso = $em->getRepository("FabricacionBundle:Aviso")->findBy(array("fecha" => $fecha));

        $dql   = "SELECT a FROM PedidosBundle:Articulo a WHERE a.aviso = :aviso";
        if(isset($_GET['filterField']) && isset($_GET['filterValue'])){
            $dql   = "SELECT a FROM PedidosBundle:Articulo a JOIN ProductosBundle:Producto p WHERE a.aviso = :aviso";
            $dql .= " AND " . $_GET['filterField'] . " LIKE '%" . $_GET['filterValue'] . "%'";
        }
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter("aviso", $aviso[0]->getId());
        //dump($query);die();
        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $articulos = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $request->query->get('page', 1),
            25
        );
```

When i dont use the filter, this work, but when i use the filter i get the next error:

```
Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction
```

Where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: try adding a four argument to the `paginate` method :                 `array("distinct" => false)`

Comment: Your query is prone to SQL injection attacks. Never ever use unsanitized user input to build up your query: `$dql .= " AND " . $_GET['filterField'] . " LIKE '%" . $_GET['filterValue'] . "%'"; `

Comment: Thank   @Matteo, but i have tried and not work :(

Comment: Hi @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan so check this in the doc: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/manual_counting.md  In some case the paginator can't find the total record numbers

Comment: Ok! i go to check this doc

Comment: Why don't you use the `QueryBuilder` for this? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: hi, let me know if you need some help about this. I usually fix with the count_hint

Answer (score 0):

What SQL engine are you running ?

Note, that it's usually a very bad practice to insert anything directly from your $_GET variable into your SQL query, as this can lead to SQL injection.
Imagine, that someone sends `\'; DROP TABLE something; --` in your `$_GET['filterField']` - everything is gone.

From the top of my head, there is a lacking JOINing condition.